# Core data executeFetchRequest consumes huge amounts of memory

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I am inserting cca 100 000 records in core data database. Database contains 3 entities.
Player, Club, PlayerClub
Entities are in relations:
Player<-->>PlayerClub<<-->Club
While inserting in PlayerClub I have noticed a lot of memory consumption and loss of speed after about 50 000 records have been inserted. Records are never updated cause PlayerClub has only unique values. 
For test reasons I have emptied Player and Club tables and run the program again. There was no speed drop but memory consumption was huge again. This is the code:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:ap.persistentStoreCoordinator];
    [context setUndoManager:nil];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PlayerClub"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSEntityDescription *entityKlubovi = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Club" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *requestKlubovi = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestKlubovi setEntity:entityKlubovi];
    [requestKlubovi setFetchLimit:1];

    NSEntityDescription *entityIgraci = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Player" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *requestIgraci = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [requestIgraci setFetchLimit:1];
    [requestIgraci setEntity:entityIgraci];

    for (int i=0; i<[parsedKlubIgraci count]; i++) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            KlubIgrac *klubIgrac = [[KlubIgrac alloc] initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];

            klubIgrac.iD = p.id;

            //... add some othe properties

            variables = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:p.igracID forKey:@"ID"];
            localPredicate = [predicateIgraci predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variables];
            [requestIgraci setPredicate:localPredicate];
            klubIgrac.igrac = [self DohvatiIgracZaIgracId:p.igracID cntx:context request:requestIgraci predicate:localPredicate];

            variables = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:p.klubID forKey:@"ID"];
            localPredicate = [predicateKlubovi predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:variables];
            [requestKlubovi setPredicate:localPredicate];
            klubIgrac.klub = [self DohvatiKlubZaKlubId:p.klubID cntx:context request:requestKlubovi predicate:localPredicate];
        }

    }
+(Club *)DohvatiKlubZaKlubId:(int)klubid cntx:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context    

    request:(NSFetchRequest *)request predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *arTmp;
        arTmp = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        Club *klub;
        if(arTmp != nil && [arTmp count]){
            return [arTmp objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }

}
```

DohvatiIgracZaIgracId method is basically the same method as DohvatiKlubZaKlubId so I dinnt post it.
This code is called about 100 000 times. The memory consumption before is about 150 MB. After it finishes its 650 MB. So it consumes 500 MB, without saving the context and without fetching anything from the database cause the tables are empty. If I comment

```
arTmp = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

line in DohvatiIgracZaIgracId and DohvatiKlubZaKlubId methods the memory consumption falls to 200 MB. So the diference is 400MB for a line of code that does nothing. This cant be. Anyone has some ideas. After a while my app consumes more than 2.5 GB.

The mesuments were done on simulator cause I need to build a database that I will preload later, so the speed is of importance :)... Thx in advance

Comment: You should probably look in to batching for CoreData.

Comment: But my fetch limit is set to 1, why do I need to use batch?

Comment: Ok I set setFetchBatchSize to 1 on both requests and O won 50 MB. Cant explain why but I did, but still 450 is tooo much :)

Comment: you probably have a retain cycle issue. [breaking retain cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMemory.html)

Comment: Could be, but the line that makes a difference fetches nothing, 0 objects, just gets called lots of time

Comment: Do you need the NSDictionary? It seems like it's just extra memory. Could you not use predicateWithFormat:@"ID = %@", p.igracID or predicateWithFormat:@"ID = %@", p.klubID?

Comment: @Jonathan, if you're doing a **lot** of passes, it can be faster to reuse a predicate with substitution vars instead of using a format every time. Using a format is conceptually simpler but requires re-parsing the format string every time.

Comment: @TomHarrington, Oh, I gotcha. It makes sense. As BoranA mentioned, you might have a strong reference cycle. According to the Core Data Programming Guide:Reducing Memory Overhead, Core Data does not by default keep strong references to managed objects (unless they have unsaved changes). If you have lots of objects in memory, you should determine the owning references. Managed objects maintain strong references to each other through relationships, which can easily create strong reference cycles.

Comment: You can break cycles by re-faulting objects (by using the refreshObject:mergeChanges: method of NSManagedObjectContext).

Comment: No objects R unfolted cause there is no objects, tables R empty. It seams that just by calling executefetch it makes memory problems

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *without saving the context*

This is the part of the question where experienced Core Data developers say "oh holy crap". That's your biggest problem right there. Save changes at regular intervals-- every 50 entries, or every 100, but whatever you do, *don't wait until you're finished*. You're forcing Core Data to keep *all* of those objects in memory as unsaved changes. This is the biggest reason you're having memory problems.

Some other things you should consider:

- Don't fetch your objects one at a time. Fetches are relatively expensive. If you run through 100k instances and fetch each of them one at a time, your code will be spending almost all of its time executing fetches. Fetch in batches of 50-100 (you can tune the number to get the best balance of speed vs. memory use). Process one batch, then save changes at the end of the batch.
- When you're done with a fetched object, tell the managed object context that you're done. Do this by calling `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` with `NO` as the second argument. That tells the context it can free up any internal memory it's using for the object. This loses any unsaved changes on the objects, but if you haven't made any changes then there's nothing to lose.
- Consider getting rid of the `PlayerClub` entity completely. Core Data supports many-to-many relationships. This kind of entity is almost never useful. You're using Core Data, not SQL, so don't design your entity types as if you were.

Comment: Nice answer. In conjunction with this note: "You're using Core Data, not SQL, so don't design your entity types as if you were." I think it's important to add that Core Data is NOT a relational database. It is an object graph.

Comment: Right. It **uses** SQLite, but that's an implementation detail. Core Data's API is very different from SQLite.

Comment: I am saving every 100 entries (in my original code). The problem is that I have to build relations during parsing. This is what I do:

Comment: I download all players, then all clubs, then I download connecting table and during save I fetch objects from clubs and players to build relation in PlayerClub. Every 100 PlayerClub entries I save the context. Is there some other way to join objects from Players and Clubs to  PlayerClub relation? I mean I can do it later after PlayerClub is completely saved, but that just seams like extra work and I am trying to make this work fast :)

Comment: I need PlayerClub cause it contains some data that I cant put in Clubs or Players, like player position in club, his status, and so on...

Comment: I marked this answer as a correct one cause of "Fetches are relatively expensive.", at the end I have rewritten my code so that it fetches all players and clubs for parsed ids before the loop and inside the loop I just predicate the fetched arrays (100 objects max), its both faster and it consumes exactly half the memory than before, so my memory consumption fell from 600 MB to 250 MB, ill say its quite enough, THANK U FOR THE ANSWER IT HELPED ALOT...