# iOS: update a core data DB with object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have this cose to update my entities:

```
for (id element in array){

    Locality *locality = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Locality" inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext];

    locality.name = [element objectForKey:@"n"];
    locality.id_locality = [element objectForKey:@"id"];


    NSFetchRequest *fetc_reg = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Region"];
    [fetc_reg setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id_region = %@",[element objectForKey:@"r"]]];
    [fetc_reg setIncludesPropertyValues:NO];
    Region *region = [[temporaryContext executeFetchRequest:fetc_reg error:&error]lastObject];
    locality.region = region;
}
```

As you can see I create a new entity called locality, it has the relationship with region so I set region for locality.
I notice that if I do this NSFetchRequest it's very expensive for the memory, because I have about 15000 locality, is there a fast way to add at locality the relationship with region?

Comment: sorry so you have this code in a for cycle? Can you post the entire ode please?

Comment: i'm trying to post the answer but stack overflow return an error

Comment: Batch fetch the entities using setFetchBatchSize:. Then, after you've fetched about 50-100 enitites and set their locality, save the context. This will cut the number of fetch requests down and lower your memory consumption. Here is a link to another question which may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952716/core-data-executefetchrequest-consumes-huge-amounts-of-memory/19960532#comment29710062_19960532

Comment: ok posted the answer.

Comment: Jonathan is correct, but I will also add to this that you will want to make sure you are not saving to your persistent store from the main thread.  The most common approach is to have a background context with a concurrency type of `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and then saving from a child context that way you aren't doing the heavy save operations on the main thread.

Comment: Yes, in fact I use a temporany context and not in the main thread. Now I save the context every 100 entites and it seems more quickly.